# Export all disabled DL members to CSV

Tags: powershell

I have an issue I've not been able to work through and I'm hoping I can get assistance. I've taken over management of 15,000+ AD user accounts and almost 1500 o365 distribution groups. I have been trying to build a command or script to query all distribution groups and export a list of user accounts that are members and do not have a mailbox.

I was able to get a working script that will find and remove them all however it is keying of disabled user accounts which would remove members that should not be. I only need group members removed that do not have a mailbox in o365. Ideally, I'd like to query the groups and export the list of group members without a mailbox to a CSV and include Name, AccountName and AccountDisabled. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Failed attempt:

```
$dg = Get-DistributionGroup 
foreach($group in $dg){
    Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $group.identity | ?{$_.recipienttype -eq 'UserMailbox'} |
        foreach{
            $mbx = Get-Mailbox $_.alias
            if($_.name -eq $mbx.name -and $mbx.AccountDisabled -eq $true){
                write-host "Removing User:" $_.alias "from group:" $group.identity
                remove-distributiongroupmember -Identity $group.Identity -Member $_.alias -Confirm:$false
                Write-Host "User Successfully Removed"
                    }    
                }
            }
```

This is the command I found which will output the user and group name to the screen and remove the group member however it is keying off disabled AD User accounts and it's outputting it in a format that won't export to csv.

Thank you
Pat

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. What do you mean “keying off disabled users” and “it’s outputting in a format that won’t export to CSV”? Your command checks for disabled accounts and just writes some status to the screen. If that’s not what you want it to do, then change it. What specific issue are you having trouble with? Need to narrow the focus here.

Comment: Hi Doug. My meaning was that this command is querying disabled user accounts in AD that are members of distribution lists in o365 and removing them from the DLs. I need to check for DL members that do not have a mailbox in o365 and then export those users to a csv so I can review the list before removing them from DLs.

 If I knew exactly how to make these changes, I wouldn't have asked for help in doing so which is why I'm here.